# Database atomic operations implementation

Tags: transaction, database-internals

The question is about queries that are not wrapped in 'begin-commit' block, but about plain inserts and updates that are atomic in PostgreSQL, MySQL (innodb engine at least). So how is this implemented internally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A transaction is started for each statement that occurs outside of an explicit transaction block. Whether a commit is automatically issued following the statement is dependent on the RDBMS configuration. MySQL has the autocommit option, SQL Server has IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS, PostgreSQL is always auto commit.

[PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-start-transaction.html):

> In the standard, it is not necessary to issue START TRANSACTION to
>   start a transaction block: any SQL command implicitly begins a block.
>   PostgreSQL's behavior can be seen as implicitly issuing a COMMIT after
>   each command that does not follow START TRANSACTION (or BEGIN), and it
>   is therefore often called "autocommit". Other relational database
>   systems might offer an autocommit feature as a convenience.

[InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-transaction-model.html):

> In InnoDB, all user activity occurs inside a transaction. If
>   autocommit mode is enabled, each SQL statement forms a single
>   transaction on its own. By default, MySQL starts the session for each
>   new connection with autocommit enabled, so MySQL does a commit after
>   each SQL statement if that statement did not return an error.

[SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174377%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> SQL Server operates in the following transaction modes.
>
> Autocommit transactions - Each individual statement is a transaction.
>
> Explicit transactions - Each transaction is explicitly started with
>   the BEGIN TRANSACTION statement and explicitly ended with a COMMIT or
>   ROLLBACK statement.
>
> Implicit transactions - A new transaction is implicitly started when
>   the prior transaction completes, but each transaction is explicitly
>   completed with a COMMIT or ROLLBACK statement.

Comment: thx Mark, things made clear. But one question about MySQL: what is autocommit is on and I wrap several queries in transaction? Wrapped transaction are not possible in MySQL as far as I'm concerned

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. [START TRANSACTION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) disables autocommit in MySQL.